# Certain number question being missed in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I have the following if statement that removes the first instances of a number followed by the period. However, I am noticing it is missing to catch some of them (ex. "16.", "23.", "24.", etc.) and not sure why.

Here is the function:

```
function quesCleanUp(ques){
  //Checks the first instance of "." and removes it and the number
  if(ques.match(/[0-9]\./g)?.length > 1){//(ques.match(/./g)?.length > 1){
    var quesClean = ques.replace(/^[^\.]*\./, '').trim();
  } else{
    var quesClean = ques.trim();
  }

  return quesClean;
}
```

The following for loop extracts the question from the google form:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
var item = items[i];
switch(item.getType()) {
  case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
    var question = item.asMultipleChoiceItem();
    var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
    var question_type = "Multiple Choice";
    var optns = [];
    var answr;
    var answers = question.getChoices();
    answer_val = false;
     for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
      var clean = answers[j].getValue().trim();
      optns.push(clean);
      if(answers[j].isCorrectAnswer()){
        answr = answers[j].getValue().trim();
        for(var x = 0; x < optns.length; x++){
            if(answr == optns[x]){
              answer_val = true;
              break;
            }
        }
      }
    }
    var multiJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
    console.log("JSON1: " + JSON.stringify(multiJSON));
    constructedJSON[i+1] = multiJSON;
    break;
  case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
    var question = item.asCheckboxItem();
    //var ques = question.getTitle().trim();//.replace(/\s/g, "");
    var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
    var question_type = "CheckBox";
    var optns = [];
    var answr = [];
    var answers = question.getChoices();
    
     for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
      var clean = answers[j].getValue().trim();//replace(/\s/g, "");
      optns.push(clean);
      if(answers[j].isCorrectAnswer()){
        answr.push(answers[j].getValue().trim());
      }
    }
    var checkJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
    console.log("JSON2: " + JSON.stringify(checkJSON));
    constructedJSON[i+1] = checkJSON;
    break;
  case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT:
    var question = item.asParagraphTextItem();
    //var ques = question.getTitle().trim();//.replace(/\s/g, "");
    var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
    var question_type = "free response";
    var optns = [];
    var answr;
    var paraJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
    console.log("JSON3: " + JSON.stringify(paraJSON));
    constructedJSON[i+1] = paraJSON;
    break;
  case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
    var question = item.asTextItem();
    //var ques = question.getTitle().trim();
    var question_type = "free response";
    var ques = quesCleanUp(question.getTitle().trim());//replace(/\s/g, "");
    var optns = "";
    var answr = "";
    var textJSON = makeJSON(ques, question_type, optns, answr);
    console.log("JSON4: " + JSON.stringify(textJSON));
    constructedJSON[i+1] = textJSON;
    break;
}
```

The following example is the type of question 16. What is the meaning of life?

And the expected output: What is the meaning of life?

Comment: `.` is a metacharacter that matches *any* character, not just a period. You do correctly escape it as `\.` in the `replace` call though?

Comment: if that is the case, why is it not missing others like 1., 2. etc @ Bergi

Comment: Because those have only a single digit I guess?

Comment: but it doesnt miss 11., 12. etc. what would be the correct way of doing it? @Bergi

Comment: Can you give an example input and expected output?

Comment: @Dogbert: Ex. 16. What is the meaning of life? should be What is the meaning of life? So it should capture the first instance of a number followed by a period

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide actual code samples of input strings and the result you expect for each. Please also show the result you actually get for each

Comment: @Phil: provided example of a question and the expected output in the edits. I also provided a for loop where it extracts the questions from the google form

Comment: It would be much simpler if you just added some strings instead of all that redundant code, eg `var input = "16. What is the meaning of life?";` expected output `"What is the meaning of life?"`, actual output `"whatever you actually got"`

Comment: @Phil: The code is needed. Yes, it would be better but there are instances where uses copy and paste questions and do not check if the format is correct. Also, would like to know why the question is being voted down? Is there something I miss to include to better clarify?

Comment: @RobertoFlores the problem with the huge block of code is that we can't run it to see what is wrong. If you instead give a list of inputs and expected outputs that you want from `quesCleanUp`, we can try to fix and improve your attempt. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RobertoFlores What's weird is that you're using different regular expressions in the `match` call and in the `replace` call. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using /[0-9]+./g to catch more than one digit

Comment: I have tried this as well and produces the same results

Answer (score 1):

As a quick fix, in the function `quesCleanUp()` try to change the line:

```
if(ques.match(/[0-9]\./g)?.length > 1){//(ques.match(/./g)?.length > 1){
```

With:

```
if (ques.match(/^[0-9]+\./g).length > 0) {
```

I suspect you got the downvotes because you posted the code with glared typos. It looks like you didn't even try to debug it first. And as the icing on the cake you accepted a wrong answer.

And probably the function can be boiled down to just one line:

```
const quesCleanUp = q => q.replace(/^\d+\./,'').trim();
```

Here is how it works:

```js
var questions = ['1. aaa', '16. What', '23. That', 'No nums'];
const quesCleanUp = q => q.replace(/^\d+\./,'').trim();

questions.forEach(q => console.log(quesCleanUp(q)));
```

Expected output:

```
aaa
What
That
No nums
```